# В чем заключается глобальный порядок S в с++ при последовательной согласованности?

Tags: c++

By Простой псевдокод.

```
Thread1: 
x.store(1); res1 = y.load();
Thread2:
y.store(1); res2 = x.load();
```

Как известно при последовательной согласованности существует 6 вариантов исполнения этого кода. Если вариантов 6, то о каком же глобальном S порядке идёт речь? Если бы он был один единственный, тогда другое дело.

Comment: *"глобальный порядок S"* ¿Вы это сами придумали? Если нет, то приводите источник и контекст.

Comment: user7860670   1)https://youtu.be/q9dXzh5yBdA 39:10

Comment: user7860670 2)https://youtu.be/aqYhCXExHBU 43:10

Comment: user7860670 3) Р. Гримм. "Параллельное программирование на современном с++". п.2.3.1.1.

Comment: user7860670 4) Э. Уильямс. "Параллельное программирование на с++ в действии". п.5.3.3.

Comment: Следовало бы привести это все в самом вопросе в виде текста, а не ссылкой на видео или каким-то упоминанием.

Comment: Вы могли бы привести определение  в тексте вопроса, что значит *глобальный порядок S* из ваших ссылок (или, хотя бы, этот **термин на английском**)? (это чтобы не гадать, об одном и том же мы думаем или нет)

Answer (score 2):

Хрустальный шар подсказывает, что в вопросе шла речь про термин `single total order`. Это свойство, которым может обладать некоторая последовательно операций. Если оно имеется, то при выполнении этих операций их порядок будет **строго одинаковым** с точки зрения всех потоков исполнения. Этим свойством могут обладать не только атомарные операции, еще этим свойством могут обладать например операции выделения удаления памяти и операции с мьютексом.

Answer (score 0):

> Если вариантов 6, то о каком же глобальном S порядке идёт речь?

Об одном из этих 6 возможных, конечно.

Идея seq-cst не в том, что он фиксирует один из возможных глобальных порядков. Идея в том, что вообще появляется хоть какой-то глобальный порядок.

С каждой atomic-переменной связан порядок операций над ней (отдельный для каждой переменной), с которым согласны все потоки (всегда, даже без seq-cst). Но без seq-cst, когда переменных несколько, разные потоки могут быть несогласны по поводу того, как перемежаются операции над *разными* переменными.

Comment: Вроде разобрался. Виноваты кэши и сторбафферы. Всем спасибо.